# How many unique combinations can be created using uppercase, lowercase letters and digits 0-9, 4 places.

Tags: combinatorics

I looked a lot of places but couldn't find an exact answer.

## Background

- I am making an application that stores transactions in a database. Each transaction has an ID.
- I need to find out if a 4 digit id will give me enough unique combinations.

## Clarifications

- By 4 digit I mean -> _ _ _ _
- Each digit can be a number (0-9) or a letter (a-z, A-Z).

How many unique combinations can be created with this?

I need about 500,000+ combinations so if this won't work, please suggest how many digits will I need. Also, could you also let me know how many digits do I need for 1 million (1, 000, 000) combinations?

Thanks so much!

P.S. I will be happy with the formula too, or a link/redirect to another site that could help!

Comment: Do you mean permutations or really combinations ?

Comment: To add extra clarity, when counting the number of combinations, AB and BA are identical (we only count them once). When counting the number of permutations, AB and BA are different and so we have two. In other words, there are always at least as many permutations as combinations since permutations count reorderings where combinations do not.

Comment: See [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) on wikipedia.  The punchline is that you have $10+26+26=62$ possible characters and four spots, assuming characters can be reused and order matters, that makes $62\times 62\times 62\times 62=14776336$ possible four-character strings you can make.  Note that some will look very similar depending on font despite being different which may affect your decision... e.g. lI0O it is unclear which is the L vs the capital i, which is the zero versus the letter Oh.

Comment: @BranBar I mean permutations. I just need unique ids: 1234 and 4321 counts as 2. Also, each digit can repeat. (1111 is valid). Is this clear enough? Thanks!